# Why did Sylar go to Kirby Plaza?

Tags: heroes

In "How to Stop an Exploding Man", Sylar goes to Kirby Plaza to confront Peter Petrelli. Why? What was his goal in going there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a two part reason, I think.

The first and primary was to kill/defeat Peter and acquire his mimicking abilities. Much of the second half of the first season deals with Sylar hunting Peter for his power.

The second sub-reason was regarding Kirby Plaza itself, and not just some random street: to fulfill the prophecy/vision he painted of Peter and Himself squaring down at Kirby Plaza.

Comment: Agreed - Sylar was obsessed with finding his purpose. Because of the painting, he felt it was his "destiny" to be there. Also, as indicated by his dialogue, he saw himself as the hero and Peter as the villain in the scenario.